# Undefined reference to static template function

Tags: c++, qt, enums, static-methods

I have a class contains common functions for my project. One of function is template static:

**common.h**

```cpp
#include <QMetaEnum>
#include <QString>

class Common
{
public:
    Common();
    template<typename T> static QString EnumToString(const T value);
};
```

and so implementation:

**common.cpp**

```cpp
template<typename T>
QString Common::EnumToString (const T value)
{
    return QString(QMetaEnum::fromType<T>().valueToKey(value));
}
```

That compiles without problems but when I want to use this functions like this:

```cpp
MyEnum enum = MyEnum::Value1;
qDebug() << Common::EnumToString<MyEnum>(enum);
```

I get some strange linker error:

> error: undefined reference to `QString
>   Common::EnumToString(MyEnum)'

MyEnum has registered in Qt metasystem:

```
enum class MyEnum
{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
};
Q_ENUM(MyEnum);
```

What I do wrong and how to get it work?

Answer (score 4):

Unspecialized templates need to be implemented in the header file.
If you put the implementation of `Common::EnumToString` inside `common.h` it will work.